# Input dialog 'select' doesn't work - Sikuli IDE 2.0.3

Tags: select, input, jython, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I'm using Sikuli IDE 2.0.3 on Windows 10. I'm writing the following script but nothing happends when I run it:

```
items = ("nothing selected", "item1", "item2", "item3")
selected = select(msg = "Please select an item from the list", title = "Año", options = items,default= items[0])
select(msg = "Please select an item from the list", title = "Año", options = items,default= items[0])
if selected == items[0]:
 popup("You did not select an item")
 exit(1)
```

it doesn't show me any error messages, apparently, the script runs normally but nothing happens. I Tried other scripts and if it works normally.

I'm using:

- sikulixide-2.0.3
- jre-8u241-windows-x64
- jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar

I'm new at this, it is possible that I am missing some parameter but I cannot find documentation about it. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the latest stable SikuliX version 2.0.4

Comment: Thanks, It works! I didn't know a new version had been released two days ago.